# How can I receive instance from another class?

Tags: java

I have `public class Human`, where located instance  `private int age;`
Also, I have `public class Student extends Human`, which accordingly inherits `Human`.
Also, I have class `Group` .

```
public class Group implements Comparable<Group>  {
    private Student[] group = new Student[10];
}
```

I want to sort students by age  `private int age`.

How can I receieve the instance `age` of the class `Human` or `Student`? I have smth like that now:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Group o) {
    return o.getAge - this.getAge;
}
```

As you can realize, I have this error:

> getAge cannot be resolved or is    not a field

Comment: you must have implemented `public int getAge()` getter inside `Human` then you will be able to access `o.getAge()` - this is really basics of Java, you should spend some time with a tutorial or documentation of Java language

Comment: if `Student` needs access to `age` variable (not an instance!)that is defined in the super class then it stands to reason that the variable will be defined `protected`. getter methods are to be used by classes not in the inheritence tree

Answer (score 1):

What you could do to fix this:

First, you have `private` field which is accessible only inside its class. In your case, you could add public methods to get/set value to make it accessible to the outside world.

```
public class Human {
    private int age;

    // public getter to get the value everywhere
    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }

    // setter to set the value for this field
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

I added `implements Comparable<Student>` to the Student class because you mention you want to compare students by age. Also, check comments :

```
public class Student extends Human implements Comparable<Student> {
    // even though it extends Human - Student has no access to private
    // fields of Human class (you can declare it as protected if you want
    // your Student to have access to that field)

    // but protected does not guarantee it will be accessible everywhere!


    // now let's say you want to compare them by age. you can add implements Comparable
    // and override compareTo. getAge() is public and is inherited from the parent
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student s) {
        return this.getAge() - s.getAge();
    }         
}
```

And your Group class needs something else. Because if this one is comparable - you compare groups, not students. And how you do it (I mean the rules like when group 1 is equal to group 2 and when it is less than group 2 etc.) - it's all up to you :)

```
public class Group implements Comparable<Group>  {
    private Student[] group = new Student[10];

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Group o) {
        // if your Group implements Comparable it means
        // you compare Groups not instances of class Student !
        // so here you need to implement rules for Group comparison !
        return .....
    }
}
```

Happy Hacking :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you added get method for the age attribute in Human class and in compareTo method change from o.getAge to o.getAge();